# Methods to ban bots, force attacks on my server

Tags: security

I've been getting some bots trying to get hold of my database by mass attacking `/sertup/scripts.php` of various database program. I wanna ban such activities.

The closest I found was this: http://www.rubyrobot.org/article/protect-your-web-server-from-spambots

What is the best way, or is there any scripts to ban bots from attacking?

Thanks.

Comment: Are there any similarities in the requests made by the bots?
Are the requests/min high?
Would a normal user/visitor access that script?

Comment: No, user/visitor won't be able to access the script. The request so far is minimum, once a week. All they were trying were various setup scripts from phpmyadmin, and other mysql controller scripts.

Comment: Cakemox answer would be the correct one. Fail2ban will track the logs for the requests made and ban them using iptables.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Fail2ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) will turn the logs of the attacks into firewall rules to block them.  It may suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I use fail2ban as well, but what proved much more useful was moving the entire site to SSL and doing a redirect. Apparently most, if not all (?) bots can't do either the redirect or SSL, so since then my fail2ban seldomly finds anything anymore.

Benefits: If you have name-based vhosts, your setup gets much simpler.